# How to solve the SWIGTYPE_p_std__complexT_double_t.java issue in SWIG

Tags: java, c++, swig

### SWIGTYPE_p_std__complexT_double_t.java

```
 /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * This file was automatically generated by SWIG (http://www.swig.org).
 * Version 4.0.2
 *
 * Do not make changes to this file unless you know what you are doing--modify
 * the SWIG interface file instead.
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


public class SWIGTYPE_p_std__complexT_double_t {
  private transient long swigCPtr;

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_std__complexT_double_t(long cPtr, @SuppressWarnings("unused") boolean futureUse) {
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_std__complexT_double_t() {
    swigCPtr = 0;
  }enter code here

  protected static long getCPtr(SWIGTYPE_p_std__complexT_double_t obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }
}
```

---

I'm using the command swig swig -c++ -java filename.i while the filename.i contains commands for parsing the c++ code to java. Adding that I'm trying to convert the complex type from c++ to java and it's here where the problem is exposed.

Comment: Make a [mcve]. Show the .i file. At a guess, `%include <std_complex.i>`

Comment: the std_complex.i works for the python environment and other languages but not the java language.

Comment: Then you have to write the typemaps yourself.